# Spring Boot Error Handling code 404 blank page

Tags: java, http, spring-boot

I am making app with Rest Services and i want to handle the exceptions and status code.
When i send the correct parametars to Postman i get the response and the status code is 202 OK so that is good.
When i send the first parameter correct and for seccond i send some chars i get status code 400 Bad Request and some message so that is good too.
But, when i send the first parameter correct and in the seccond i delete one number i am getting Status: 404 Not Found (Which is correct) and blank page in Postman without some message.
[image]
So my question is:
Is that alright to get only status code 404 and blank page or i need to change something in the code to get the message too.

My second question is about Internal Server Error 500. How can i implement it and how to test it?

```
@CrossOrigin
@RequestMapping(value = "/blaa/{startDate}/{endDate}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity<List<Nodes>> listsOfbla(@PathVariable Long startDate,
        @PathVariable Long endDate) {

    startEndDateRequestTotal.inc();

    List<Nodes> listOfbla= NodesService.getFromToData(startDate, endDate);

    LOG.info("GET Request was made with two paramaters ", startDate, endDate);
    for (int i = 0; i < listOfbla (); i++) {
        if (listOfbla(i).getStampm().equals(startDate)) {
            for (int j = 0; j < listOfbla (); j++) {
                if (listOfbla(j).getStampm().equals(endDate)) {
                    return new ResponseEntity<List<Nodes>>listOfbla HttpStatus.OK);
                }
            }
        } else {
            return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
        }
    }

    if (listOfbla.isEmpty()) {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
    }
    LOG.info("Retruning Nodes objects from specified date");
    return new ResponseEntity<List<Nodes>>(listOfbla, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

Comment: Your method requires both path variables to be matched, if one is missing, the endpoint is considered as not found.

Comment: Yes but my message is about the blank page. I think there should be some error message?  Something like this:
{
    "timestamp": 1515140227701,
    "status": 400,
    "error": "Bad Request",
    "exception": "blaldalsd"
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your first question:
That is enough you receive the status code and you can make for example.
If status code = 404 send me this message.

Comment: thank you for the answer. The GUI guy can see the error code.